# JavaScript object has no method

Tags: javascript, casting

I'm working on an application that uses JavaScript VERY heavily. I'm serializing JSON objects across pages, and I'm wondering if that is causing problems. If we ignore the serization, my code basically looks like this:

```
function MyClass() { this.init(); }
MyClass.prototype = {
    init: function () {
          var cd = new Date();
          var ud = Date.UTC(cd.getYear(), cd.getMonth(), cd.getDate(), cd.getHours(), cd.getMinutes(), cd.getSeconds(), cd.getMilliseconds());

        this.data = {
          currentDateTime = new Date(ud);
        }
    }
}

try {
  var myClassInstance = new MyClass();
  alert(myClassInstance.data.currentDateTime.getFullYear());
} catch (e1) {
  console.log(e1);
}
```

When I execute my "alert", I get an error that says:

"Object 0112-03-14T10:20:03.206Z has no method 'getFullYear'"

I can't figure out why I'm getting this error. I clearly have some object. However, I anticipate that it is some typing issue. Yet, I don't understand why. Is there a  way to do a type check / cast?

Comment: Just to be clear: You cannot serialize JSON. JSON is already a textual representation of data. You probably meant that you are serializing JavaScript objects. Also your code should not even give you that error, because `currentDateTime = new Date(ud);` is invalid JavaScript there. If you fix this, it works: http://jsfiddle.net/yTVmj/

Comment: in this context what does `this` refer to.  You may need to pass in the objects context

Comment: @Michael: `this` refers to what ever `this` refers to in `this.init()`. And that will be an empty object inheriting from `MyClass.prototype` if called with `new MyClass()` (as it is done in the code).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try changing this:

```
this.data = {
    currentDateTime = new Date(ud);
}
```

to this:

```
this.data = {
    currentDateTime: new Date(ud)
}
```

Inside an object literal, you need to use `:` to map keys to values.

Comment: Remove the semicolon (;) from the end of your line.

Comment: Welcome and no problem, we all are in hurry. :-)

Answer (score 2):

```
this.data = {
  currentDateTime = new Date(ud);
}
```

should be:

```
this.data = {
  currentDateTime: new Date(ud)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a syntax error in your `this.data` definition...

instead of

```
currentDateTime = new Date(ud);
```

make it...

```
currentDateTime : new Date(ud)
```

Otherwise your code copied to jsfiddle **[works](http://jsfiddle.net/VfkrN/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

`currentDateTime = new Date(ud);` should be `currentDateTime : new Date(ud);`

```
this.data = {
    // Initialize as a property
    currentDateTime : new Date(ud)
}
```

Which is the same as:

```
this.data = {
    currentDateTime: function() {
        return new Date(ud);
    }
}
```