# object has no method onFrame

Tags: javascript, methods, kineticjs

sorry for what is probably a really dumb question but I am trying to learn how to use KineticJS and am trying to modify a tutorial (http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/labs/html5-canvas-star-spinner/) to use a static image instead of a shape. For what it's worth, I'm trying to animate a PNG of Glenn Beck's head to make it spin (neither here nor there really).

I've muddled through a bunch of errors so far but I keep getting stuck with "Uncaught TypeError: Object# has no method 'onFrame'"

I've read multiple questions about objects/methods here on SO and other sites and while I think I understand what the problem is, I'm not sure how to fix it:

[object Object has no method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11261009/object-object-has-no-method)

[JavaScript object has no method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9703880/javascript-object-has-no-method)

[contains is object has no method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12342787/contains-is-object-has-no-method)

From what I understand, the "no method" errors mean there is no function available to be called..? Surely "onFrame" exists inside Kinetic, though..? I tried looking through the Kinetic docs to see if they changed the name between 3.8.X (the tutorial) and 4.X (the library I am using) but it doesn't appear as though they did.

Here is my code:

```
<head>
    <script src="http://test.XXXXX.com/js/kinetic-v4.3.2.js"></script>
    <script>
        function animate(animatedLayer, beck, frame){
            var canvas = animatedLayer.getCanvas();
            var context = animatedLayer.getContext();

            // update
            var angularFriction = 0.2;
            var angularVelocityChange = beck.angularVelocity * frame.timeDiff * (1 - angularFriction) /     1000;
            beck.angularVelocity -= angularVelocityChange;

            if (beck.controlled) {
                beck.angularVelocity = (beck.rotation - beck.lastRotation) * 1000 / frame.timeDiff;
                beck.lastRotation = beck.rotation;
            }
            else {
                beck.rotate(frame.timeDiff * beck.angularVelocity / 1000);
                beck.lastRotation = beck.rotation;
            }

            // draw
            animatedLayer.draw();
        }

        window.onload = function(){
            console.log('stage =', stage); // DEBUG
            var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({ container: "container", width: 240, height: 320 });
            console.log('stage =', stage); // DEBUG
            var backgroundLayer = new Kinetic.Layer();
            var animatedLayer = new Kinetic.Layer();


            var beck = new Image();
              beck.onload = function() {

                    var beck = new Kinetic.Image({
                      x: 240,
                      y: stage.getHeight() / 2 - 59,
                      image: beckHead,
                      width: 150,
                      height: 230
                    });
                beckHead.src = "http://test.XXXXX.com/i/beckhead.png";
                animatedLayer.add(beck);
             };



            stage.on("mousedown", function(evt){
                this.angularVelocity = 0;
                this.controlled = true;
            });

            // add listeners to container
            stage.on("mouseup", function(){
                beck.controlled = false;
            }, false);

            stage.on("mouseout", function(){
                beck.controlled = false;
            }, false);

            stage.on("mousemove", function(){
                if (beck.controlled) {

                    var mousePos = stage.getMousePosition();
                    var x = (stage.width / 2) - mousePos.x;
                    var y = (stage.height / 2) - mousePos.y;
                    beck.rotation = 0.5 * Math.PI + Math.atan(y / x);

                    if (mousePos.x <= stage.width / 2) {
                        beck.rotation += Math.PI;
                    }
                }
            }, false);


            stage.add(backgroundLayer);
            stage.add(animatedLayer);

            // draw background
            var context = backgroundLayer.getContext();
            context.save();
            context.beginPath();
            context.moveTo(stage.width / 2, stage.height / 2);
            context.lineTo(stage.width / 2, stage.height);
            context.strokeStyle = "#555";
            context.lineWidth = 4;
            context.stroke();
            context.restore();

            stage.onFrame(function(frame){
            console.log("onFrame fired")
                animate(animatedLayer, beck, frame);
            });


            stage.start();
        };
    </script>
</head>
<body onmousedown="return false;">
    <div id="container"><canvas id="container"></canvas>
    </div>

</body>
```

Comment: It seems that the example has been updated. I think the author listens to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is outdated example which uses version 3.8.4

```
<script src="http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/libraries/kinetic-v3.8.4.js">
```

, and the current version is > 4.3

```
<script src="http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/libraries/kinetic-v4.3.0-beta2.js"></script>
```

The current version does not have methods like Stage#onFrame and Stage#start.

You can use this example, http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/kineticjs/html5-canvas-kineticjs-rotation-animation-tutorial/ as your base, then add stage.on("mouseup/down/move/out") to catch mouse movement and affect animation.

The perfect answer would be conversion of that old example to the new version one, which I may try in the future.